# remove and store multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have hidden inputs that remove badges from certain pools/groups.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Remove[<?= $i; ?>][Badge][id]" value="<?= $badge['id']; ?>" data-id="<?= $badge['id']; ?>" />
```

I'm relatively new to JS and JQuery but here is what I have so far...

```
$('.glyphicon-remove').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('remove');
        $(this).siblings().removeAttr("name value data-id");
        return false;
    });
```

The problem is when they click on the `.glyphicon-remove` I need it to toggle those attributes. I also played around with the JQ function detach but was unable to use it with the attr() tag.

I need to be able to toggle each of these attributes on each click. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or if I can clarify my question in anyway.

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.7 or above? Does `$(this).parent()` return the correct element?  Does `$(this).siblings()` return the correct elements?

Comment: jQuery UI - v1.8.21. Both the siblings and parent selectors do return the correct elements.

Comment: `.attr({
    name:"", 
    value:"",  data-id:""
});`

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of `toggleAttr` that keeps the old value to restore.
Try the following:

```
$('.glyphicon-remove').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('remove');
    var sib = $(this).siblings();
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('remove')) {
        //Stores attrs to correspontent data-* attribute
        sib.each(function(){
           $(this).data("name", $(this).attr("name"));
           $(this).data("value", $(this).attr("value"));
           $(this).data("data-id", $(this).attr("data-id"));
        });
        sib.removeAttr("name value data-id");
    } else {
        //Restores attrs from the correspondent data-* attribute
        sib.each(function(){
           $(this).attr("name", $(this).data("name"));
           $(this).attr("value", $(this).data("value"));
           $(this).attr("data-id", $(this).data("data-id"));
        });
        sib.removeData("name");
        sib.removeData("value");
        sib.removeData("data-id");
    }
    return false;
});
```